# What's the effect of waterwark for event time based interval join

Tags: apache-flink

I know that late events will be dropped by default if it is late and its belonging window is closed.
I would ask how aboult event time based interval join?  what's the exact behavior/effect of watermark? will the late events dropped?

Comment: Are you referring to the DataStream API or Flink SQL?

Comment: Are there difference between datastream api and flink sql? I like to know both, thanks @snntrable.Could you please help answer? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally: A watermark indicates to Flink, that all records with up the timestamp of the watermark have arrived. All elements with a timestamp lower than the watermark (the minimum watermark of both sides) are considered "late".

For interval joins in FlinkSQL and the DataStream API (KeyedStream#intervalJoin) there are two separate implementations [1,2], but the answer is the same: late events will be dropped.

Interestingly, the Flink SQL operator has an allowed lateness field, but it is always initialized with `0L` [2]. So it seems, there might be plans to extend this functionality.

[1] https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/co/IntervalJoinOperator.java#L230

[2] https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-table/flink-table-planner-blink/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/planner/plan/nodes/physical/stream/StreamExecIntervalJoin.scala#L313

Comment: Sure, thanks @snntrable for the great help.

Comment: No worries, could you accept the answer if it answered your questions. Thanks :)

Comment: sure,thanks @snntrable, I just forgot about that,:-)